# gcc -fsanitize multidimensional array

Tags: c++, gcc

When compiling a cpp program like

```
int main() {
  int a[5][5];
  cout << a[5][5];
}
```

compiled with -fsanitzie=address I got the runtime exception, but

```
int main() {
  int a[5][5];
  cout << a[3][5];
}
```

which is also out of range does not trigger this.
Is there anyway to make gcc also check for multidimensional arrays, that all indices are in range.

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that -fsanitize=bounds would do the trick.